# scipy curve fitting negative value

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I would like to fit a curve with `curve_fit` and prevent it from becoming negative. Unfortunately, the code below does not work. Any hints? Thanks a lot!

```
# Imports
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = [0.0009824379203203417, 0.0011014182912933933, 0.0012433979929054324, 0.0014147106052612918, 0.0016240300315499524, 0.0018834904507916608, 0.002210485320720769, 0.002630660216394964, 0.0031830988618379067, 0.003929751681281367, 0.0049735919716217296, 0.0064961201261998095, 0.008841941282883075, 0.012732395447351627, 0.019894367886486918, 0.0353677651315323, 0.07957747154594767, 0.3183098861837907]

yData = [99.61973156923796, 91.79478510744039, 92.79302188621314, 84.32927272723863, 77.75060981602016, 75.62801782349504, 70.48026800610839, 72.21240551953743, 68.14019252499526, 55.23015406920851, 57.212682880377464, 50.777016257727176, 44.871140881319626, 40.544138806850846, 32.489105158795525, 25.65367127756607, 19.894206907130403, 13.057996247388862]

def func(x,m,c,d):
    '''
    Fitting Function
    I put d as an absolute number to prevent negative values for d?
    '''
    return x**m * c + abs(d) 

p0 = [-1, 1, 1]
coeff, _ = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, p0) # Fit curve
m, c, d = coeff[0], coeff[1], coeff[2]

print("d: " + str(d)) # Why is it negative!!
```

Comment: Why would adding `abs(d)` prevent d from becoming negative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model actually works fine as the following plot shows. I used your code and plotted the original data and the data you obtain with the fitted parameters:

[image]

As you can see, the data can nicely be reproduced but you indeed obtain a negative value for `d` (which must not be a bad thing depending on the context of the model). If you want to avoid it, I recommend to use `lmfit` where you can constrain your parameters to certain ranges. The next plot shows the outcome.
[image]

As you can see, it also reproduces the data well and you obtain a positive value for `d` as desired.

namely:

```
m:  -0.35199747 
c:   8.48813181 
d:   0.05775745
```

Here is the entire code that reproduces the figures:

```
# Imports
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#additional import
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit

xData = [0.0009824379203203417, 0.0011014182912933933, 0.0012433979929054324, 0.0014147106052612918, 0.0016240300315499524, 0.0018834904507916608, 0.002210485320720769, 0.002630660216394964, 0.0031830988618379067, 0.003929751681281367, 0.0049735919716217296, 0.0064961201261998095, 0.008841941282883075, 0.012732395447351627, 0.019894367886486918, 0.0353677651315323, 0.07957747154594767, 0.3183098861837907]
yData = [99.61973156923796, 91.79478510744039, 92.79302188621314, 84.32927272723863, 77.75060981602016, 75.62801782349504, 70.48026800610839, 72.21240551953743, 68.14019252499526, 55.23015406920851, 57.212682880377464, 50.777016257727176, 44.871140881319626, 40.544138806850846, 32.489105158795525, 25.65367127756607, 19.894206907130403, 13.057996247388862]

def func(x,m,c,d):
    '''
    Fitting Function
    I put d as an absolute number to prevent negative values for d?
    '''
    print m,c,d
    return np.power(x,m)*c + d

p0 = [-1, 1, 1]
coeff, _ = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, p0) # Fit curve
m, c, d = coeff[0], coeff[1], coeff[2]

print("d: " + str(d)) # Why is it negative!!
plt.scatter(xData, yData, s=30, marker = "v",label='P')
plt.scatter(xData, func(xData, *coeff), s=30, marker = "v",color="red",label='curvefit')
plt.show()

#####the new approach starts here
def func2(params, x, data):

    m = params['m'].value
    c = params['c'].value
    d = params['d'].value

    model = np.power(x,m)*c + d
    return model - data #that's what you want to minimize

# create a set of Parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('m', value= -2) #value is the initial condition
params.add('c', value= 8.)
params.add('d', value= 10.0, min=0) #min=0 prevents that d becomes negative

# do fit, here with leastsq model
result = minimize(func2, params, args=(xData, yData))

# calculate final result
final = yData + result.residual

# write error report
report_fit(params)

try:
    import pylab
    pylab.plot(xData, yData, 'k+')
    pylab.plot(xData, final, 'r')
    pylab.show()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this worked and saved my early day. Now I can prevent my curves from going into the negative value range.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` method's `bounds` option to specify the maximum bound and the minimum bound.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Bounds is a two tuple array. In your case, you just need to specify the lower bound for d. You could use, 
`bounds=([-np.inf, -np.inf, 0], np.inf)`

Note: If you provide a scalar as a parameter (eg:- as the second variable above), it automatically applies as the upper bound for all three coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one little argument to constrain your parameters. That is:

`curve_fit(func, xData, yData, p0, bounds=([m1,c1,d1],[m2,c2,d2]))`

where m1,c1,d1 are the lower bounds of the parameters (in your case they should be 0) and 
m2,c2,d2 are the upper bounds.

If u want all m,c,d to be positive, the code should goes like the following:

`curve_fit(func, xData, yData, p0, bounds=(0,numpy.inf))`

where all the parameters have a lower bound of 0 and an upper bound of infinity(no bound)